# RuntimeError: Graph is finalized and cannot be modified

Tags: python, tensorflow, sentencepiece

After running below sample:

```
def embed_muse(module):
    with tf.Graph().as_default():
        sentences = tf.placeholder(tf.string)
        embed = hub.load(module)
        embeddings = embed(sentences)
        session = tf.train.MonitoredSession()
    return lambda x: session.run(embeddings)
embed_fn = embed_muse(module)

messages = [
    "we are sorry for the inconvenience",
    "we are sorry for the delay",
    "we regret for your inconvenience",
    "we don't deliver to baner region in pune",
    "we will get you the best possible rate"
]
embed_fn(messages)
```

following error raised:
raise RuntimeError("Graph is finalized and cannot be modified.")

Tensorflow version:'2.2.0'

Comment: you are running TF1 code in TF2. Downgrade your tensorflow version, or [migrate your code to TF2](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/migrate?hl=en).

Comment: I have migrated my  Tensorflow version to TF version: 1.15.0 but still error not resolved.

Comment: Is your issue resolved now? Else, can you send standalone code to replicate your issue? so that we can help you. Thanks!